# Hi, How to deploy multiple frontend angular applications on localhost using ingress routes (Kubernetes)

Tags: angular, kubernetes

I have two frontend angular applications. I have to deploy them on local kubernetes cluster.
one is exposed on port 3000 and other on 3001 in docker.
I have exposed nodeport 30000 on localhost using HELM command with traefik.

```
 helm install --replace traefik --namespace=traefik --set "service.type=NodePort" --set "ports.web.nodePort=30000" traefik/traefik
```

I have ingress routes with rule like below for one front end .

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: app-ingressroute
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`localhost:30000`) && PathPrefix(`/`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: app-frontend-cluster-ip-service
          port: 3000
```

So after deploying, i can see first frontend application on `localhost:30000/`

For the second frontend application, either i should expose one more port say 30001 and use that in ingress, which im not sure if it is possible using HELM command.
I tried adding pat prefix like below for second frontend application on same host like below:

```
- match: Host(`localhost:30000`) && PathPrefix(`/frontend2`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: app-frontend2-cluster-ip-service
          port: 3001
```

Also, i have given `<base href="/frontend2/">` in `index.html` of second frontend application.

But when i try to give `http://localhost:30000/frontend2/` in browser , i'm getting

```
uncaught syntax error: unexpected token < which point to index.html file.
```

Kindly help if there is any solution.

Comment: Hi there. Ideally you deploy one Ingress controller. In this case you've gone with Traefik. Then you deploy multiple `Ingress` objects. These direct the traffic based on criteria. For example you can direct the traffic based on hostname or path or both. Pick how you want to direct it first. Would you like for example: /app1/ and /app2/ ?

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear, you currently are using "/" and "/frontend2" which will not work. It can't tell where to send what. It would be better to have /frontend1 and /frontend2